Would kite rigs be competitive with traditional sails and wingsails?
This was originally a part of this question, but I decided they were big enough and different enough to be split up.
Kite rigs are, like wingsails, an alternative to conventional sails. They take advantage of the fact that winds are both stronger and more consistent at higher altitudes, something at least one species in my setting is intuitively aware of, meaning they would likely be developed much sooner than in our world. Notably, they can tack into the wind just like sails can, although only up to 50° into the wind (worse than either traditional sails or wingsails).
The Wikipedia page notes that they improve the fuel efficiency of fossil-fuel powered ships in the real world, but has no comparisons to conventional sails or wingsails. Would kite rigs be something that ships in a pre-industrial setting would want, to supplement or even replace their conventional sails and possibly wingsails?

This isn't a worldbuilding question. We don't deal with Real World engineering. We focus on suspension of disbelief in an imaginary world of your own creation (see [help/on-topic]). From a Real World perspective, kite rigs would never be (and, historically, weren't) competitive with traditional sails because the first time the wind dies you're trying to haul them out of the water and damaging them with every pull. But in your imaginary world, nothing stops you from switching that around. What's stopping you from using kite rigs in your world?

@JBH I'm not sure I agree with that. The question is basically "If a fictional society developed traditional sails and kite rigs simultaneously, which one sees widespread adoption?" I'm not asking for engineering fixes to the problems with kite rigs (or wingsails in the other question), I'm asking if making them a prominent setting element would damage suspension of disbelief for people who know more about sails than I do (and thus if I need to come up with some fixes or abandon the idea).

I would like to qualify @JBH's comment. I often see real engineering and hard science questions asked, loved, and answered here. But they are always for problems out of our current grasp. Something that requires extrapolation beyond what is currently understood. In your case, there is likely an obvious and boring answer like "they are not as practical" since the problem and technology have long been around.

@PoeticallyPsychotic societies don't create things like kite rigs and sails simultaneously. Human histoy has ample examples of how technology builds on technology. Sails can be made with coarse cloth. Kites cannot. For sails to have not existed until kite-capable cloth came along makes no sense. But that doesn't mean it can't be rationalized. But you're not asking questions in a way Stack Exchange can handle. I strongly suggest you take advantage of our Sandbox.

A lot of the choices of building ship and rigging ships comes down to tradition (like how the western world has basically settled on the bermuda rig for small boats, despite the eastern junk rig beeing arguably better for recreational non racing use). If you manage to start a strong tradition using kitesails I don't see a fundamental problem with it catching on.
There are a few obstacles and downsides though and its not a good fit for all situations.

You need a relatively abundant source of of material for a strong lightweight, water repellant cloth, and for the lines.
Maybe a type of Silkworm that is far bigger and more productive than the real world counterpart. Wool is likely not gonna fly, literally.
A minimal viable kitesail is more complicated than a minimal viable normal sail.
A kite needs constant monitoring by a person, preferably by actively flying it - a moving kite can generate more energy than a static one. Onlike normal sails you can put up once and not touch again until weather conditions or your course changes.
A kite is not easily sized down then the wind picks up. You need a set of different sizes and strenghts for different conditions.
There will be a maximum size for a kite that you can manufacture and handle. Thats also the maximum size of your sail area on that ship, since using multiple kites is asking for trouble. While you can add a lot of normal sails to a ship.
Starting and landing kites will likely be a hassle.
Maneuvering near other ships or the shore/harbor will also be tricky.

Now to the upsides:

You get more energy per sail area
No large mast is needed
No heeling over
Less impact from wind disturbance by (low lying) land/trees near the shore.

You need to decide if this will make it viable in your setting.
Likely not for any large european style vessels (unless you somehow find a low tech way to build and handle really large kites), but maybe for indonesian-sized boats.
You could combine it with a free standing mast with conventional sails, but you don't want something with a lot of standing rigging, that will likely get in the way.
